# poner cursor al inicio de la consola en java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

¿como puedo poner el cursor al inicio de la consola de eclipse con java? me refiero a programaticamente, es decir desde codigo java. He intentado cientos de pruebas pero no he conseguido nada.
Quiero hacer un juego de tetris en la consola (simulando los cuadraditos con dos corchetes []). Entonces tengo que imprimir la pieza que esta en juego y para simular movimiento imprimirla varias veces en distintas posiciones. Y para ello tengo que imprimir el area de juego continuamente con la pieza en las distintas posiciones.

este es el main:

```
public class tetris {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        areaDeJuego area=new areaDeJuego();
        while(true)
        {
            area.mostrar();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            area.girarPiezaReloj();
        }               

    }
}
```

esta es la clase areaDejuego:

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class areaDeJuego {  
    private Posicion[]espacio=new Posicion[10*20];
    private Pieza piezaEnJuego=new PiezaT(new Posicion(0,0),0,new Color(223, 45, 223));
    
    public areaDeJuego()
    {
        int indice=0;
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                espacio[indice]=new Posicion(i,j);              
                indice++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void girarPiezaReloj()
    {
        piezaEnJuego.rotarReloj();
    }
    
    public void girarPiezaContraReloj()
    {
        piezaEnJuego.rotarContraReloj();
    }
    
    public void moverDerecha()
    {
        piezaEnJuego.desplazarDerecha();
    }
    
    public void moverIzquierda()
    {
        piezaEnJuego.desplazarDerecha();
    }
    
    public void mostrar()
    {
        vaciarPantalla();
        for(Posicion casilla:espacio)
        {
            boolean encontrado=false;           
            for(Posicion elemento:piezaEnJuego.getForma())
            {               if(elemento.getF()+piezaEnJuego.getPosicion().getF()==casilla.getF() && elemento.getC()+piezaEnJuego.getPosicion().getC()==casilla.getC())
                {
                    
                    System.out.print("[]");
                    encontrado=true;
                }               
            }           
            if(!encontrado)
            {
                System.out.print("..");
                
            }
            if(casilla.getC()==9)
            {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void vaciarPantalla()
    {
        
    }

}
```

esta es la clase piezaT:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class PiezaT extends Pieza{

    //Toma 4 posiciones al rotar
    private static final Posicion[] FORMA0 = { new Posicion(0,0), new Posicion(0,1), new Posicion(0,2), new Posicion(1,1)};
    private static final Posicion[] FORMA1 = { new Posicion(0,0), new Posicion(1,0), new Posicion(1,1), new Posicion(2,0)};
    private static final Posicion[] FORMA2 = { new Posicion(0,1), new Posicion(1,0), new Posicion(1,1), new Posicion(1,2)};
    private static final Posicion[] FORMA3 = { new Posicion(0,1), new Posicion(1,0), new Posicion(1,1), new Posicion(2,1)};
    
    public PiezaT(Posicion posición, int rotacion, Color color) {
        super(posición, rotacion, color);
        setForma(FORMA0);
    }
    
    public void rotarContraReloj()
    {
        switch( getRotacion())
        {
        case 0:
            setRotacion(3);
            setForma(FORMA3);
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 1:
            setRotacion(0);
            setForma(FORMA0);
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setRotacion(1);
            setForma(FORMA1);
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 3:
            setRotacion(2);
            setForma(FORMA2);
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        }

        
        while(estaFueraPorIzquierda())
        {
            desplazarDerecha();
        }
        while(estaFueraPorDerecha())
        {
            desplazarIzquierda();
        }
    }
    public void rotarReloj()
    {
        switch( getRotacion())
        {
        case 0:
            setRotacion(1);
            setForma(FORMA1);
            //System.out.println("forma3");
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 1:
            setRotacion(2);
            setForma(FORMA2);
            //System.out.println("forma2");
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 2:
            setRotacion(3);
            setForma(FORMA3);
            //System.out.println("forma1");
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        case 3:
            setRotacion(0);
            setForma(FORMA0);
            //System.out.println("forma0");
            getPosicion().setF(getPosicion().getF()+1);
            getPosicion().setC(getPosicion().getC()-1);
            break;
        }

        
        while(estaFueraPorIzquierda())
        {
            desplazarDerecha();
        }
        while(estaFueraPorDerecha())
        {
            desplazarIzquierda();
        }
        
    }
}
```

y esta es la clase pieza:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public abstract class Pieza {

     private Posicion posicion; 
     private int rotacion; //indica el estado de rotación de la pieza (por ejemplo 1, 2, 3, 4).
     private Color color;
     private Posicion[] forma;
     
     //Delimitadores del juego
     private static final int LIMITE_COLUMNAS=10;
     private static final int LIMITE_FILAS=20;
     
     
    public Pieza(Posicion posición, int rotacion, Color color) {
        this.posicion = posición;
        this.rotacion = rotacion;
        this.color = color;
        //this.forma = forma;
    }
     
    public void desplazarDerecha() {
        boolean puedeDesplazarse=true;
        for (Posicion casilla:forma)
        {
    
            if(posicion.getC() + casilla.getC()-1>LIMITE_COLUMNAS)
            {
                puedeDesplazarse=false;
            }
        }
        if(puedeDesplazarse)
        {
            posicion.setC(posicion.getC()+1);
        }
         
     }
    public void desplazarIzquierda() {
        
        boolean puedeDesplazarse=true;
        for (Posicion casilla:forma)
        {
            if(posicion.getC() + casilla.getC()-1<0)
            {
                puedeDesplazarse=false;
            }
        }
        if(puedeDesplazarse)
        {           
            posicion.setC(posicion.getC()-1);
        }
         
     }
    public void desplazarAbajo() {
        
        boolean puedeDesplazarse=true;
        for (Posicion casilla:forma)
        {
            if(posicion.getF()+casilla.getF()>LIMITE_FILAS)
            {
                puedeDesplazarse=false;
            }
        }
        if(puedeDesplazarse)
        {
            posicion.setF(posicion.getF()+1);
        }
        
         
     }
     
    public abstract void rotarReloj();
    public abstract void rotarContraReloj();
     
     //Métodos getters y setters
    public Posicion getPosicion() {return posicion;}
    public void setPosición(Posicion posicion) {this.posicion = posicion;}
    public int getRotacion() {return rotacion;}
    public void setRotacion(int rotacion) {this.rotacion = rotacion;}
    public Color getColor() {return color;}
    public void setColor(Color color) {this.color = color;}
    public Posicion[] getForma() {return forma;}
    public void setForma(Posicion[] forma) {this.forma = forma;}
     
    public boolean estaFueraPorDerecha()
    {
        for (Posicion casilla:getForma())
        {
            if(posicion.getC()+casilla.getC()>=LIMITE_FILAS)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public boolean estaFueraPorIzquierda()
    {
        for (Posicion casilla:getForma())
        {
            if(posicion.getC()+casilla.getC()<0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

lo que necesito definir ahora es la funcion `vaciarPantalla()` de la clase areaDeJuego.

Comment: Hola! Disculpa, necesitamos que nos ayudes añadiéndole más detalle a la pregunta para poder entender qué quieres :)

Comment: ya he editado la pregunta.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaah, ok. Quieres que, **al correr tu programa Java**, cuando muestra la salida en la consola que está _incorporada_ en Eclipse, el cursor vuelva a la primera posición. ¿Eso? ¡Implica que debes INCLUIR tu código en la pregunta para revisar qué hacer! (por ahora, sospecho que la solución va a pasar por limpiar y pintar la pantalla cada cierto tiempo, pero para una respuesta, necesitamos ver tu código!)

Comment: ya he añadido el codigo

Answer (score 0):

con esto he conseguido borrar la consola de windows:

```
public static void clrscr(){
    //Clears Screen in java
    try {
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))
            new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
        else
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

pero sigo sin conseguir borrar la consola de eclipse.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé... java no va a poder borrar la consola de eclipse, puesto que esa consola se borra desde el botón que tiene eclipse para ello, no es una consola *normal* como la de windows... La manera más fácil de *"borrarla"* será imprimir un montón de líneas en blanco, usando algo así: `System.out.println(new String(new char[20]).replace("\0", "\r\n"));` puedes imprimir 20 saltos de línea en un momento. Basta con que cambies el 20 por la cantidad que te haga falta para *limpiar* la consola y ala